# Свайп как на картинке

Tags: android

Это картинка из одной детской программы, в котором есть алфавит. Там свайпом влево или вправо или стрелками можно перелистывать буквы. Хотелось бы узнать как это вообще реализовано? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: скорее всего это на основе [виджета ViewFlipper](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/viewflipper.php)

Comment: ViewFlipper вроде не поддерживает перелистывание пальцем или поддерживает? А там пальцем тоже можно переключать

Comment: Готового механизма нет, но реализуется через слушатель OnTouchListener (или аналогичные, от задачи) довольно просто.

Comment: Мм понял.. А по вашему какой компонент лучше использовать? Я ни с тем ни с другим пока не работал. Предполагаю что данные буду выводить из БД или Json. Наверное из json скорее всего, чтобы не заморачиваться из базой

Answer (score 1):

Конкретно сказать, что используется в описанном Вами приложении не решусь, но есть такой стандартный компонент, как [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html), с помощью которого можно реализовать подобную задачу.

Для его использования придётся добавить в зависимости следующую библиотеку:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1' // или более новую версию
}
```

Comment: спасибо почитаю про него.