# Переход по фрагментам по нажатию на кнопки

Tags: android

Есть адаптер

```
public class AlphabetPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    List<Letter> data;

    public AlphabetPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Letter> data) {
        super(fm);
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {

        Fragment fragment = new AlphabetFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(AlphabetFragment.ARG_LETTER, data.get(i).getLetter());
        args.putString(AlphabetFragment.ARG_IMAGE, data.get(i).getImage());
        args.putString(AlphabetFragment.ARG_DESCRIPTION, data.get(i).getDescription());
        args.putString(AlphabetFragment.ARG_AUDIO, data.get(i).getAudio());
        args.putInt(AlphabetFragment.ARG_POSITION, i+1);

        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Item " + (position + 1);
    }
}
```

И класс в котором формируется сам фрагмент

```
public class AlphabetFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_IMAGE = "image";
    public static final String ARG_POSITION = "item_position";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.alphabet_fragment, container, false);
        Bundle args = getArguments();

        ImageButton btnPrev = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnPrev);
        ImageButton btnNext = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnNext);

        imgLetter.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromAssets(args.getString(ARG_IMAGE)));


        imgLetter.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                play(mSound);
                return false;
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmapFromAssets(String filename) {
        AssetManager assetManager = this.getContext().getAssets();
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = assetManager.open("img/alphabet/" + filename);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопки btnPrev переходило к предыдущему фрагменту, а по нажатию на btnNext - к следующему?

ARG_POSITION - как я понимаю содержит текущий id фрагмента

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть предположение, что это как-то связано с [этим вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/653531/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BF-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B5/653549#653549). Первая мысль, которая пришла в голову, что Вы семья, и что Вы решили сэкономить деньги на покупке приложения для ребенка, создав собственное :)

Не обижайтесь, просто для меня тема детских приложений и их дороговизны пока еще актуальна :)

Что касается вопроса, то не все поймут, что у Вас происходит без действительно нужных подробностей. Если бы я недавно не отвечал на вопрос связанный с `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, то наверное прошел бы мимо :)

Предположение о нужных подробностях следующее - у Вас есть `Activity`, в котором есть `ViewPager`, в который Вы поместили `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

Если всё верно, то решение Вашей проблемы будет на уровне `Activity`. Добавьте в `Activity` следующие методы:

```
public void onNext() {
    PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();
    int currentPosition = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
    int nextPosition = currentPosition + 1;
    if (nextPosition < adapter.getCount()) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(nextPosition);
    } else {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }
}

public void onPrevious() {
    PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();
    int currentPosition = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
    int previousPosition = currentPosition - 1;
    if (previousPosition >= 0) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(previousPosition);
    } else {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(adapter.getCount() - 1);
    }
}
```

ну а внутри Ваших `AlphabetFragment` вешайте на `ImageButton` следующие `Listener`-ы:

```
btnPrev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ((YourActivity) getActivity).onPrevious();
    }
});

btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ((YourActivity) getActivity).onNext();
    }
});
```

`YourActivity` переименуйте на собственное название :)

А вообще Вы конечно намудрили с архитектурой, когда можно было бы обойтись единственным уровнем Activity, поместив во ViewPager сразу картинки и всего две кнопки "туда" - "обратно".

А так Вы поместили во `ViewPager` фрагменты, в которые Вы поместили картинки и метод их изъятия, в каждом фрагменте собственные кнопки "туда" - "обратно".. много лишнего кода и объектов в приложении :)

Вот пример адаптера без использования `Fragment`, слегка адаптированный под Ваши нужды, мне лень кучу кода липить, а потому предположим что Вы класс адаптера держите прямо внутри Вашей Activity:

```
private class AlphabetPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
        View view = ((LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
                .inflate(R.layout.alphabet_fragment, null);
        // alphabet_fragment переименуйте потом :)
        ImageView imgLetter = (ImageView) view.findViewById(/*id*/)
        imgLetter.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromAssets(data.get(i).getImage());
        imgLetter.setOnTouchListener(mImageOnTouchListener);

        collection.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
        collection.removeView((View) view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }
}
```

`mImageOnTouchListener` я не с проста предложил создать единожды, есть предположение (у меня недостаточно кода, да и дальше мне всё равно уже лень), что Ваш код можно оптимизировать до одного `OnTouchListener` на все картинки, меняя переменную `mSound`.

Что касается кнопок "Туда"-"Обратно", то их нужно вынести в разметку самой `Activity`, расположив поверх `ViewPager`-а (это значит, что они должны быть обязательно добавлены в разметке после `ViewPager`-а, т.к. все `View` накладываются на макет поочерёдно).

Вам еще очень поможет добавление `Listener`-a во `ViewPager`:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // тут меняйте значение mSound
        // это будет как-то связано с Вашим кодом  data.get(position).getAudio()
    }
};
```

Comment: Я хочу чтобы отображалось несколько картинок, проигрывался звук вместе с этим. И была возможность перелистывать туда и обратно. Как это можно сделать тогда без фрагментов?

Comment: И что писать в методе getCurrentItem();

Comment: В методе getCurrentItem() ничего писать не надо, это обычный getter, возвращающий значение текущей позиции, относительно всего списка :)

Comment: Я хотела чтобы был эффект перелистывания. И посмотрев какие для этого есть компоненты решила что удобнее будет ViewPager. И для того чтобы знать про этот компонент хотелось бы докончить этот вариант

Comment: Чтобы Вас не путать, ViewPager компонент, созданный именно для эффекта  перелистывания. Вы могли создать собственный адаптер наследованный сразу от PagerAdapter, который мог выдавать на выходе сразу разметку для страницы. А значит количество компонентов содержащих картинки было бы таким же. Но кнопки "Туда" "Обратно" были бы в единственном экземпляре поверх ViewPager-a статичными, что смотрелось бы логичнее, плюс не было бы уровня Fragment. Но это лишь моё мнение. А сейчас главное помочь Вам решить поставленный вопрос :)

Comment: Я пробовала реализовать подобный вариант, но запуталась. И решила готовое решение, которое нашла в интернете под свои нужны переделать. Можете скинуть ссылку на пример реализации вашего способа?

Comment: Вынесла кнопки в активити из фрагмента и в AlphabetActivity реализовала методы onNext и onPrevious. Работает, спасибо. Но если вы подсказываете лучший вариант реализации того что мне нужно (А именно отображение 3 картинок и проигрывания аудио и возможность это все листать туда обратно), я бы изучила и если смогу разобраться реализовала бы такой вариант. Только все примеры, которые я смотрела была похожи на мои.

Comment: И метод getBitmapFromAssets() прямо в AlphabetPagerAdapter добавить?

Comment: Обновил, перечитайте всё еще раз заново, а то я там много очепяток исправил :)

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо. Попробую разобраться

Comment: да, забыла отметить. Спасибо