# Два раза проигрывает аудио во фрагменте

Tags: android

Непонятная проблема. При открытии Activity проигрывает сразу букву А и букву Б.

Класс Activity

```
public class AlphabetActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton btnBack;
    ImageButton btnPrev;
    ImageButton btnNext;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    List<Letter> data = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alphabet);

        AlphabetPagerAdapter mTextPagerAdapter = new AlphabetPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager(), getData());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.alphabetPager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mTextPagerAdapter);
    }

    private List<Letter> getData() {
        List<Letter> data = new ArrayList<>();

        data.add(new Letter("А", "bukva_1_big.png", "bukva_1_little.png", "Арбуз", "bukva_1.mp3"));
        data.add(new Letter("Б", "bukva_2_big.png", "bukva_2_little.png", "Банан", "bukva_2.mp3"));
        data.add(new Letter("В", "bukva_3_big.png", "bukva_3_little.png", "Волк", "bukva_3.mp3"));

        return data;
    }
}
```

Класс адаптера

```
public class AlphabetPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    List<Letter> data;

    public AlphabetPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Letter> data) {
        super(fm);
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {

        Fragment fragment = new AlphabetFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(AlphabetFragment.ARG_LETTER, data.get(i).getLetter());
        args.putString(AlphabetFragment.ARG_IMAGE_BIG, data.get(i).getImageBig());
        args.putString(AlphabetFragment.ARG_IMAGE_LITTLE, data.get(i).getImageLittle());
        args.putString(AlphabetFragment.ARG_DESCRIPTION, data.get(i).getDescription());
        args.putString(AlphabetFragment.ARG_AUDIO, data.get(i).getAudio());
        args.putInt(AlphabetFragment.ARG_POSITION, i);

        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Item " + (position + 1);
    }
}
```

Класс фрагмента

```
public class AlphabetFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_LETTER = "letter";
    public static final String ARG_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    public static final String ARG_IMAGE_BIG = "imageBig";
    public static final String ARG_IMAGE_LITTLE = "imageLittle";
    public static final String ARG_AUDIO = "audio";
    public static final String ARG_POSITION = "item_position";

    String mSound;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.alphabet_fragment, container, false);
        Bundle args = getArguments();

        ImageView imgLetter = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgLetter);

        imgLetter.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromAssets(args.getString(ARG_IMAGE_BIG)));

        mSound = args.getString(ARG_AUDIO);

        play(mSound);

        imgLetter.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                play(mSound);
                return false;
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmapFromAssets(String filename) {
        AssetManager assetManager = this.getContext().getAssets();
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = assetManager.open("img/alphabet/" + filename);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    void play(String filename) {

        try {
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = this.getContext().getAssets().openFd("sound/alphabet/" + filename);
            MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
            mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
            mp.setLooping(false);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Где я ошибку допустила? Пол часа пытаюсь разобраться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В методе `onCreateView` Вы вызываете `play(mSound);`

`ViewPager` устроен так, что он подготавливает заранее изображения соседних страниц, таким образом Вы и слышите звуки поочередно подготовленных `Fragment`.

Более того, если бы Вы заранее выбирали `Fragment` с буквой `Б`, то порядок озвучивания был бы `Б`-`В`-`А`. Потому что первым создался бы выбранный `Fragment`, затем следующий по списку от первого, а затем предыдущий по списку от первого.

В [предыдущем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/662071/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8/662185#662185) я говорил, что Вам очень поможет использование `Listener`-а во `ViewPager`-е. Если Вы хотите при переключении `Fragment`-a проигрывать букву на экране, то установите метод проигрывания в этот `Listener`:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        play(mSound); // адаптируйте под свой код
    }
};
```

Comment: А где вызывать метод play()? И еще такая проблема, думаю все из-за того же Перешла на букву Б и возвращаюсь назад (используя ваш метод для кнопки Назад) и он перекидывает на букву Я

Comment: с буквой Б потом Я - это мой косяк, я поправил в ответе код в условии к кнопке назад, там теперь if (previousPosition >= 0),  а было просто "больше"

Comment: А как решить проблему с воспроизведением аудио два раза?

Comment: Я так поняла addOnPageChangeListener нужно добавлять в сам AlphabetActivity. А тогда как теперь вытащить переменную mSound? Ведь в нее значение записывается во фрагменте

Comment: mSound = mTextPagerAdapter.data.get(mViewPager.getCurrentItem()).getAudio();   так? Где getAudio() метод из вспомогательного класса Letter

Comment: вынесете метод play(), а заодно и getBitmapFromAssets() в отдельный класс в папку utilit, сделайте методы статичными и обращайтесь к ним через класс.

Comment: Я вынесла метод play в AlphabetActivity и пытаюсь так воспроизводить  mSound = mTextPagerAdapter.data.get(mViewPager.getCurrentItem()).getA‌​udio();  viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        play(mSound); // адаптируйте под свой код
    }
};

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58248/discussion-between-artilirium-and-).